# How to have hero image to occupy all of the screen height 100%

Tags: css

I just want my hero image to fit 100% height (I have used 500px height is fiddle because that's how its working otherwise just NO output) and doesn't care about the width so that it takes whole screen on desktops as well as mobiles. I referred to other questions out there but they didn't solve my issue.

Here's the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/qrgLvaue/

```
.hero-image{
    background-size: cover;
    background: url(http://www.intrawallpaper.com/static/images/hd_wallpapers_gg3.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    height: 500px;
    -o-background-size: cover;}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just update your code to `height: 100vh;` and put `background-size: cover;` after your background shorthand property.

```
.hero-image{
    background: url(http://www.intrawallpaper.com/static/images/hd_wallpapers_gg3.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qrgLvaue/1/

Comment: vh and other such units are overrated. there will be a problem in case of scrollbars.

Comment: `vh` is way to go in modern web development for issues like this.

Comment: It worked like a charm btw. But when I scroll a little bit on my mobile, the position of the image gets a little bit changed. I don't want it that way obviosly

Comment: I guess you will have to figure that new issue out by yourself. I did, though, tell you how to fix your initial question's problem.

Comment: Gave your answer a tick. :)

Comment: @UmerJaved You can also add this to your code:  
 background-attachment:fixed; so you dont have the scroll issue

Comment: I did that using javascript and its working perfectly fine. $(window).ready(function(){
  $("#full-height").height($(window).height()+"px");
});

Comment: This will fail as soon as the window height changes (for example because someone turns their iPad sideways). To solve that, you would have to attach a listener to the resize event (or at least orientation change event) which I would not recommend for performance reasons. Also, there is no JS necessary here.

Answer (score 0):

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: url(http://www.intrawallpaper.com/static/images/hd_wallpapers_gg3.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  overflow: auto;
  counter-reset: i;
}

div {
  background: url(http://www.intrawallpaper.com/static/images/hd_wallpapers_gg3.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
}

div:after {
  counter-increment: i;
  content: counter(i);
  color: white;
  font-size: 10em;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: I can't put the image on body as it will display on whole page.

Comment: Although my desired output is somehow the same but there will be other elements too after this hero image.

Comment: @UmerJaved, updated the answer. If it's not what you want, I don't understand your question.